# Concatenate list of ints in java 8

Tags: java, string, list, java-8, java-stream

How can I concatenate list of ints

```
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
Optional<Integer> result = numbers.stream().reduce((subtotal, element)-> Integer.valueOf(subtotal + ", " + element));
```

But I got an exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1, 2"
>       at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)

Comment: What is wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1, 2"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Unknown Source)
 at Test.lambda$0(Test.java:10)
 at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$2ReducingSink.accept(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown

Comment: how do you expect `(subtotal + ", " + element)` to have an `Integer` value?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you wanna do it using `reduce`  convert Integers into Strings and then use Accumulator function

```
Optional<String> result = numbers.stream().map(i->i.toString()).reduce((i,j)->i+", "+j);
```

Or you can simply use `Collectors.joining`

```
String str = numbers.stream().map(i->i.toString()).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

Comment: There is not much benefit though IMHO, in this much of an effort versus a simple `String str 
 = numbers.toString()`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `String.join` for that. It joins given `Iterable` of `CharSequence` with specified delimiter (`", "` in your case):

```
List<String> strings = numbers.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.toList())

String concatenated = String.join(", ", strings)
```